# Doubts regarding decision trees and random forest classifier (scikit)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I am a newbie to decision tree, so might be these are trivial questions.

Decision Trees:

1. As per scikit doc (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), "predict_proba" function returns the probability of each class, which is the fraction of training samples of the same class in a leaf. What exactly does that mean.

Random Forest Classifier:

1. What is the advantage of taking samples with replacement (bootstrapping) in random forest classifier. What extra benefits it offer over Pasting, i.e to take random subsets of datasets (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html)
2. There is a parameter in scikit random forest classifier as " bootstrap_features" ( features are drawn with or without replacement). What exactly does it mean to draw feature with replacement. As per my understanding while growing a tree you cannot use same feature again. So what exactly does it mean to replace a feature.
3. What is the intuition behind to learn variable importance from Random Forest Classifier.

Answer (score 1):

### DT

> As per scikit doc (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), "predict_proba" function returns the probability of each class, which is the fraction of training samples of the same class in a leaf. What exactly does that mean.

If you grow your tree without a limit - it means nothing, predict proba will alway output 100%. However, if you somehow restrict the size of the tree (for example by max_depth) then some leafs actually will end up with samples from **different classes**, then predict proba, if classification finishes in such leaf, returns a probability of each class proportional to each class samples in this leaf. For example, you end up with a leaf with 3 samples from class 1 and 2 from class 2, then if you end up in this leaf you output [0.6 0.4] (3/(3+2)=3/5=0.6 = 60% is a probability that you should assign class 1, and 2/(3+2)=2/5=0.4 = 40% for class 2.

### RF 1

> What is the advantage of taking samples with replacement (bootstrapping) in random forest classifier. What extra benefits it offer over Pasting, i.e to take random subsets of datasets (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html)

It makes your training set equal in size of the original one, thus you can more or less use the same range of hyperparameters you would use for a single tree. Furthermore this makes training sets more diverse (as you have artificial "boosting" of some samples, which are drawn multiple times). It also has better statistical properties thus leads to better estimates of properties of an estimator (such as its generalization capabilities)

### RF 2

> There is a parameter in scikit random forest classifier as " bootstrap_features" ( features are drawn with or without replacement). What exactly does it mean to draw feature with replacement. As per my understanding while growing a tree you cannot use same feature again. So what exactly does it mean to replace a feature.

[No, there is not](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

> class sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,
>   criterion='gini', max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2,
>   min_samples_leaf=1, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, max_features='auto',
>   max_leaf_nodes=None, **bootstrap=True**, oob_score=False, n_jobs=1,
>   random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False, class_weight=None

maybe you mean generic Bagging? Then you can have multiple use of each feature.

### RF 3

> What is the intuition behind to learn variable importance from Random Forest Classifier.

This is just a measure of for how many samples each feature is used among the trees to make a decision, thus - lower the score, the less you lose if you drop this feature from your dataset. You can use it in various ways, including feature selection, feedback for data analysis, etc.

> The relative rank (i.e. depth) of a feature used as a decision node in a tree can be used to assess the relative importance of that feature with respect to the predictability of the target variable. Features used at the top of the tree are used contribute to the final prediction decision of a larger fraction of the input samples. The expected fraction of the samples they contribute to can thus be used as an estimate of the relative importance of the features.

Comment: Thanks for DT and RF3

Regarding RF1, I am confused, how sampling will give the size of original set. Also, how this artificial boosting good of samples is good and how generalisation is better.

Regarding RF2, Sorry for the mistake. Yes it is used in generic bagging (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#bagging-meta-estimator). What is the significance of it being there?